# Unable to upload pdf file in POST request using Cypress 6.4.0 & TypeScript

Tags: cypress

I am writing API tests using Cypress 6.4.0 & TypeScript where I need to upload a pdf file in the request body.
My code for the request is:

My code for the request body is:

```
 public async createAssetDocTest() {
        let url = sharedData.createAsset_url + sharedData.assetA;
        let response = await fetch(url
            ,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: await requestbody.createAssetDocBody(),
                headers: {
                    Authorization: sharedData.bearer + " " + adminTokenValue,
                    Accept: sharedData.accept,
                    'Content-type': sharedData.docReqContent,
                },
            }
        );
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200);

    public async createAssetDocBody(): Promise<any> {
        const file = sharedData.doc;
       cy.fixture(file).then((pdfDoc) => {
            Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(
                pdfDoc,
                sharedData.contentTypeValue
            ).then(async (blob: string | Blob) => {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.set(sharedData.document, blob, file);
    
                const body = {
                    formdata: {
                        document: {
                            value: pdfDoc,
                            options: {
                                filename: sharedData.document,
                                contentType: null,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                };
                return body;
            });
        });
    }
```

However, the file does not upload the file & the request fails with error 400. Is there a better way to upload files in the body of the POST request?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz0g0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue!

**The main issue was that my Cypress version was too old. Upgraded to 9.7.0**

Then added the following code:

```
public async createAssetDoc(): Promise<any> {
    cy.fixture("pic location", "binary")
        .then((file) => Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(file))
        .then((blob) => {
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("document", blob, "pic location");
            const url = "your url";

            cy.request({
                url,
                method: "POST",
                body: formdata,
                headers: {
                    Authorization:
                        "bearer" + " " + token,
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
            }).then((response) => {
                expect(response.status).to.equal(201);
                expect(response.statusText).to.equal(
                    sharedData.fileUploadStatusText
                );
                  const finalResponse = String.fromCharCode.apply(
                            null,
                            new Uint8Array(response.body)
                        );
                        return finalResponse;
            });
        });
}
```